# Apply a condition automatically if there is a change in some cells

Tags: vba, excel

I want to fill automatically a cell whenever a range of cells changes ("C2:C5"). and it doesn't work...

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Celula As String
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("C2:C5")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("U2").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then

        On Error Resume Next
            Celula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hlookup("2017-S1", Range("D11:AF11"), 1, True)
        On Error GoTo 0
            Range("U2") = Celula

    End If

End Sub
```

if i put only this(and run manually) it works:

```
Sub Teste()

    Dim Celula As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("U2").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    On Error Resume Next
        Celula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hlookup("2017-S1", Range("D11:AF11"), 1, True)
    On Error GoTo 0
        Range("U2") = Celula

End Sub
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Storax Answer is absolutely right. Your code is executed but the change to the worksheet fires the change event again and the cell is cleared again... but this time the condition is not met, so that it stays empty.

Comment: it still doesn't work... 
the function Hlookup it supposed to return someting and the cell "U2" stays empty, why?

Comment: could you post your changed code? i tested it and it worked.

Comment: could you put a breakpoint into the method and see if the code gets executed?

Comment: If your code doesn't get executed reopen the workbook. it seems, that your EnableEvents didn't got changed to true somewhere... so no events are called

Comment: when i step throught the code, it doesn't do anything after "is nothing then", it jumps directly to "End if". I reopen the workbook, and it still doesn't work.. :/